# Match function definition using regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, c++14

I want to match a function definition. Function definition can be like

```
int foo () {
    // Some statement
}
int foo(int a, int b){}
int foo ()
{
}
```

I have written a regex `foo\s*\([\w, ]*\)\s*{` and tried it in atom text editor and it is running fine. But when I try to run it in C++14 complier it gives me regex_error(). My C++ regex is `regex b("foo\s*\([\w, ]*\)\s*{");`. I have  also tried double escaping the brackets as `\\(` but still it's not working.

Comment: Use `regex b(R"(foo\s*\([\w, ]*\)\s*\{)");`

Comment: Escaping the back-slashes is a good starting point. You *must* do that (if you use normal strings and not raw strings).

Comment: It's also high time for you to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it worked.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will keep that in mind

Comment: Regexes just aren't powerful enough to match a C function declaration, and you want to use them for a C++ function definition?

Comment: C++ function definitions can be *extremely* complex. I doubt you'll be able to successfully match all of standalone functions, member functions, lambda functions, template functions, etc, all with qualifiers like `&&`, `const`,  `volatile`, `virtual`, `override`, and much more - there's also function (forward) declarations that can appear in both global and function scope etc.. It's *much* more complicated than you think and regular expressions are just not the right tool to parse C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex contains an unescaped `{` char that is fine in a PCRE regex you tested at regex101.com, but the `std::regex` default regex engine does not allow an unescaped `{` that should match a literal `{` char.

Besides, it is best practice to use a raw string literal to define regex patterns, as the backslashes in regex escape sequences do not need escaping.

So, you may fix your current regex as

```
regex b(R"(foo\s*\([\w, ]*\)\s*\{)");
```

Or, you may modify the pattern to match all from `foo(` to last `){` on a line by replacing `[\w, ]*` with a greedy dot pattern `.*`:

```
regex b(R"(foo\s*\(.*\)\s*\{)");
```

See a [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/Wf19c3):

```
regex r(R"(foo\s*\([\w, ]*\)\s*\{)");
string s("int foo () {\n    // Some statement\n}\nint foo(int a, int b){}\nint foo ()\n{\n}");
for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                         i != std::sregex_iterator();
                         ++i)
{
    std::smatch m = *i;
    std::cout <<  m.str() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
foo () {
foo(int a, int b){
foo ()
{
```